# SkSpriteNode collision not being detected

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Im using Sprite Kit to detect collision between two objects. Here is how I define their bitmasks.

```
static const uint32_t puffinCategory = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t planeCategory = 0x1 << 1;
```

Here is my code as to how setup the puffins and planes physics body. 
For puffin

```
SKSpriteNode *PuffinNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"puffin"];
    PuffinNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:PuffinNode.size];
    PuffinNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    PuffinNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = puffinCategory;
    PuffinNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    PuffinNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = puffinCategory;
    PuffinNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = planeCategory;


    [PuffinNode setZPosition:1.5];
```

For Plane

```
SKSpriteNode *planeSpriteNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:planeStringFileName];
planeSpriteNode.position = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height*-1);
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:planeSpriteNode.size];
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = planeCategory;
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = puffinCategory;
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = puffinCategory;
```

Here is my implementation of the delegate method didBeginContact:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
    NSLog(@"collission method run");
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & puffinCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & planeCategory) != 0 ){
        NSLog(@"collission occured");
    }   
}
```

Im not seeing the method logging if it is called, nor do I see a log when the two sprites collide.

Comment: Didn't you forget to set the `SKScene`'s `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` ?

Comment: That is done within didMoveToView method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set

```
PuffinNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

and

```
planeSpriteNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

two static bodies cannot collide, at least one should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Some problems :

1) Did you set the SKScene's `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` ?
2) Both of your nodes have no dynamic. If you want them to interact in the physics world you should make them under physics laws. One of them at least must be dynamic.
3) Your `collisionBitMask` are not well set.